# In Deno's assertThrowsAsync(), where are standard exception types found to test for specific exceptions

Tags: unit-testing, deno

In the following Deno test snippet:

```js
    await assertThrowsAsync(
      async (): Promise<void> => {
        for await (const entry of walk('./non-existent-directory')) {
          console.log(entry)
        }
      },
      NotFound,
      'No such file or directory'
    )
```

Deno spells out the type and message to the console `NotFound: No such file or directory (os error 2)`

but where is that `NotFound` exception declared?  When I run the snipped as is using [deno 1.0.5's standard testing library](https://deno.land/std/testing) , I get `error: TS2304 [ERROR]: Cannot find name 'NotFound'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deno specific errors can be accessed through [`Deno.errors`](https://doc.deno.land/https/github.com/denoland/deno/releases/latest/download/lib.deno.d.ts#Deno.errors).

For `NotFound` you should use:

```js
await assertThrowsAsync(
  async (): Promise<void> => {
    for await (const entry of walk('./non-existent-directory')) {
      console.log(entry)
    }
  },
  Deno.errors.NotFound,
  'No such file or directory'
)
```

Here's the full list:

```
Deno.errors.NotFound
Deno.errors.PermissionDenied
Deno.errors.ConnectionRefused
Deno.errors.ConnectionReset
Deno.errors.ConnectionAborted
Deno.errors.NotConnected
Deno.errors.AddrInUse
Deno.errors.AddrNotAvailable
Deno.errors.BrokenPipe
Deno.errors.AlreadyExists
Deno.errors.InvalidData
Deno.errors.TimedOut
Deno.errors.Interrupted
Deno.errors.WriteZero
Deno.errors.UnexpectedEof
Deno.errors.BadResource
Deno.errors.Http
Deno.errors.Busy
```